# github authentication for my meteor application

Tags: node.js, meteor, github-api, meteorite

Can anyone suggest me the best method of authentication for my application?

I'm creting an application where I need the user to login into gmy app using  services like fb,google and twitter

My application needs  github or linkedin data of a user

I don't want to merge the login account with this account, so I'm trying to use a node package

I'm decided to use this package

`https://github.com/michael/github`

and here I see two types of authentications

`https://github.com/michael/github#usage`

which one is best for my requirement?

**If anyone want further info I will provide. I'm not getting which other info is helpful**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the oauth option. This is because all of the required login types you mentioned also implement oauth login. You should be able to implement **one** oauth login which will work across your login types.

Take a look here: http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/08/oauth-io